# Code works in watir-classic but not in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

When I write the blow code in `Watir-webdriver`:

`$browser.checkbox(:index,0).click`

It gives the following error:

> element not visible   (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.97)   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

and then I have written this code `$browser.input(:index,0).click` then it reports this error:

> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (952, 17). Other
>   element would receive the click: ... 
>   (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.97)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)

But the element is clearly visible and also the given above two lines of code cleanly works in `watir-classic`, we do not even need to scroll the screen.

Can anyone suggest me why it is the case? Why this `watir-webdriver` is not as comfortable as `watir-classic`?

```
<td class="centred"> <label class="label-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="cover.IsSelected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> <div class="fake-checkbox"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </div> </label> </td>
```

Comment: When clicking elements, Watir-Classic does not ensure that the element is visible. In contrast, Watir-Webdriver does make a visibility check. If you can share the HTML and CSS that reproduces the problem, we can give you a more specific reason for why this problem is occurring.

Comment: hi Justin,given below code has text box, this text_box works when I write code 'b.text_field(:name,'some').set in watir-webdriver but it doesn't work in watir-classic.

<input type="email" class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email" name="emailReEnterPolicyholder" id="emailReEnterPolicyholder" placeholder="Required" data-ng-model="phContact.PrimaryEmailAddressReenter" data-ng-required="true" data-da-confirm-input="" data-da-confirm-input-field-to-compare="phContact.PrimaryEmailAddress" data-prevent-cut-copy-paste-input="" required="required">

Comment: Please do not enter code as a comment; instead, edit your question to include the properly-formatted code.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will do it. .

Comment: Hi Justin, I have added code above in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to [update your chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), as version 2.9 is 2 years old. That binary needs to be kept up to date with current versions of chrome. It is quite likely that this alone will fix your issue.

If it is an issue of visibility... The purpose of Watir (and Selenium and WebDriver) is to mimic the action of a user. If the checkbox isn't visible to the user, you shouldn't be able to click it in your test.

If the checkbox is something that isn't visible at first, but then becomes visible, you can do: `browser.checkbox.when_present.click` (note that `index: 0` is the default behavior and is not necessary)

If the checkbox has some exciting javascript things that are covering it up in a way that it is never going to be visible, and clicking on something that is visible throws the "Element not clickable" error, you might have to do `browser.checkbox.when_present.fire_event :click`
That method does not mimic what a user actually does on your site, so it should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: ". The purpose of Watir (and Selenium and WebDriver) is to mimic the action of a user. If the checkbox isn't visible to the user, you shouldn't be able to click it in your test."

But Can I overcome this problem? That means Can I make watir-web driver to not to check the visibility like it's happening in watir-classic? Watir-classic automatically scrolls the browser If element is available.

Comment: "and clicking on something that is visible throws the "Element not clickable" error, you might have to do browser.checkbox.when_present.fire_event :click"

Thank you, I was not aware of this information.

Comment: 'But Can I overcome this problem?' I'm saying it is a feature not a problem. Did Chromedriver 2.21 make a difference? Does it work with internet explorer or Firefox? Did the fire event method work for you?

Comment: "But Can I overcome this problem?' I'm saying it is a feature not a problem. " But I am saying I don't want this feature, it's creating unnecessary problem for me, Classic is very fine in this place. Can I anyway switch off this checking? "Did Chromedriver 2.21 make a difference?" That doesn't make any difference. "Does it work with internet explorer or Firefox?" Watir-webdriver is very worst when I tend to drive the IE browser. "Did the fire event method work for you?" Yeah I have already used this, this works, thanks.

Comment: I'm glad the fire_event works for you, but no, there will be no toggle to turn off a feature that is fundamental to the purpose of the project. IE Driver is difficult to write and maintain, due to Microsoft limitations, hopefully their work on creating their own driver for Edge will alleviate these issues in the future.